fetch api structure for FormData
I am creating structure for FormData in fetch API, but there is something that i am missing. it will be helpful if someone can help me. Here is the code.


const fetchFormData = async (url, method = 'POST', formData) => {
  const secret = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY || '';
  const token = Cookies.get('accessToken');

  if (!secret) {
    throw new Error('Secret key is not defined');
  }

  if (!token) {
    throw new Error('Token is not defined');
  }

  const payloaddata = formData; 
  const nonce = generateNonce();
  const timestamp = generateTimestamp();
  const signature = generateSignature(JSON.stringify(payloaddata), secret, nonce, timestamp);

  const headers = {
    'Nonce': nonce,
    'Timestamp': timestamp,
    'Signature': signature,
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method,
      headers,
      body: formData,
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export default fetchFormData;

And here i am consuming:

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', bulkFile)
    const apiUrl = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL_LIVE}/uploadProducts`
    try {
      const response = await fetchFormData(apiUrl,'POST',formData)

      const responseData = await response.json()
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(responseData.message || `Failed to fetch data, status: ${response.status}`)
      }
    catch(error){
    console.log(error.message)
    }

i am trying to upload csv file on server but for error. Before that, i was using regular method and it was working absolutely fine but in fetch api structure, i got an error

You are not passing the method correctly. It's a key:value pair and you are passing a string value as a parameter. When it arrives at the function call it parses the fetch options argument into { headers, 'POST', body}  rather than below
{
      method: method,
      headers,
      body: formData,
    }

const response = await fetchFormData(apiUrl,'POST',formData)
